# Finish a symmetrical map

Tags: code-golf, string

You are given one-quarter of a map that is symmetrical over the x- and y-axes as input. The program should print the complete map.

The map can contain the following characters: `-+/\|.`, and they should be turned as expected. The in data is always rectangular and small.

### Example

```
$ cat in
+---
|./.
|/..

$ ./solution < in
+------+
|./..\.|
|/....\|
|\..../|
|.\../.|
+------+
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: What exactly does *small* mean for the input data? That's a bit vague to quantify.

Comment: @Joey Let's say the input is at most 16 rows and 40 characters.

Comment: I realised that I put no time limit, but if someone needs more than a second for his solution, I'd really like to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Golfscript - 32 chars

```
n%{{.-1%{.3%2=115*^}%+}%zip}2*n*
```

Due to the symmetry of the problem, we repeat twice {flip horizontally, transpose (`zip`)}. As a bonus, you can change the value `2` to a larger number to repeat the image more.

Character transposition is done as `x^=155 if x%3==2`, due to the restricted character space. There's also `{.5^3%(45+}` at the same length.

Answer (score 4):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/wiki), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
║Ｑ↷↷
```

First Canvas answer, so let's start with an easy one. :)

-1 byte thanks to *@dzaima*.

The slashes are automatically converted when mirroring or rotating in Canvas.
Could have been 1 byte `╬` ([Try it online](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTZD,i=JTYwJTYwJTYwJTBBKy0tLSUwQSU3Qy4vLiUwQSU3Qy8uLiUwQSU2MCU2MCU2MA__,v=8)), but unfortunately it also transforms the dots `.` to single quotes `'` when mirroring horizontally.

[Try it online.](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTUxJXVGRjMxJXUyMUI3JXUyMUI3,i=JTYwJTYwJTYwJTBBKy0tLSUwQSU3Qy4vLiUwQSU3Qy8uLiUwQSU2MCU2MCU2MA__,v=8)

**Explanation:**

```python
         # (Take the multi-line input implicitly as canvas object)
║        # Palindromize the canvas object (without overlap)
 Ｑ      # Output it with a trailing newline (without popping)
  ↷↷    # Rotated the canvas object that's still on the stack by 90 degrees twice
         # (and output it implicitly as well at the end)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Windows PowerShell, 99 <s>103</s> <s>117</s> <s>126</s> <s>129</s>

```
filter x{$_-split'/'-replace'\\','/'-join'\'}$input|%{$_+-join($_[40..0]|x)}|%{$_
$s=,($_|x)+$s}
$s
```

Notes:

- This unfortunately needs two things that PowerShell is notoriously bad at while golfing: Reversing a string (or sequence of values) and transliterating stuff in a string. I'm fairly sure that this is at least twice as long as a Perl of Ruby solution.

Test:

```
> gc in| .\map.ps1
+------+
|./..\.|
|/....\|
|\..../|
|.\../.|
+------+

> gc in2
+\/
/\/
> gc in2| .\map.ps1
+\/\/+
/\/\/\
\/\/\/
+/\/\+
```

History

- 2011-02-09 11:10 (129) – First attempt.
- 2011-02-09 11:27 (126) – `OFS` to save the `-join` and stored `99..0` in a variable.
- 2011-02-09 11:31 (117) – `-replace` works against arrays, so I don't need three `-replace`s but can do a `-split`, `-replace`, `-join` instead.
- 2011-02-09 15:03 (105) – Instead of doing the same thing twice, do it once and reverse it. And putting an assignment into parentheses causes it to spit out its value to the pipeline :-)
- 2011-02-09 15:08 (103) – I don't need `$a` anymore since `99..0` isn't used that often by now.
- 2011-02-09 15:17   (99) – There doesn't need to be whitespace after the `filter` definition. Removed `$x` and instead collecting every line during the first run in an array and then outputting that for the second half.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby - <strike>88</strike> 87 chars

```
t=->s{s.tr'/\\\\','\\\\/'}
puts a=$<.map{|l|l.chop!+t[l.reverse]}
puts a.reverse.map &t
```

### Test Run

```
D:\tmp>ruby cg_sym_map.rb < sym_map.in.
+------+
|./..\.|
|/....\|
|\..../|
|.\../.|
+------+
```

Comment: Nice, I like the puts-assignment.

Comment: Ah, there's my demise ;-) I knew it would come eventually

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ｓ‖Ｍ⌈
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Neil*.

Charcoal automatically handles reflecting the slashes correctly.

[Try it online (verbose)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0JLikKDMvXUOTKyg1LSc1ucQ3s6gov0jD6lFPh@b//9FKSkraurq6XDV6@npcNfp6ekCB2P@6ZTkA) or [Try it online (pure)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9ns2PGqa937P2UU/H///RSkpK2rq6ulw1evp6XDX6enpAgVgA).

**Explanation:**

Take the input as a string:

```
InputString()
Ｓ
```

Reflect mirror it both towards the right and downwards (`:⌈` is a builtin for `:Right, :Down`):

```
ReflectMirror(:⌈)
‖Ｍ⌈
```

Comment: @ASCII-only has since added some more multidirectionals including `⌈` which gives you right and down in a single byte.

Comment: @Neil How do you use `⌈` in the Verbose code? `:RightDown` will of course not be the result we'd want.

Comment: Multidirectionals just take a `:` prefix in Verbose mode.

Comment: @Neil So `:Right:Down`, or `::RightDown`, or something else? Neither of these two results will give a `⌈` in the encoded version with the `-vl` argument, though. What would the verbose code have to become to get `Ｓ‖Ｍ⌈` when using the `-vl` arg?

Comment: `ReflectMirror(:⌈)`

Comment: @Neil Ah, I'm an idiot.. lol. Similar as `:^` or `:*` of course. Thanks.

Comment: (Actually ⌈ means :Right, :Down rather than :Down, Right. Only makes a difference for some operations such as Polygon.)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>25</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```apl
(⌽⍪⊖){⊃3⌽⍵∪'/\'}¨,⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbBI1HPXsf9a561DVNs/pRV7MxmLv1Uccqdf0Y9dpDK3SAAv//JyoAlT7qalLX1tXVVedK1IFya/T09ZC5@nogLojXNjGRK00hEQA)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 80 chars

```
print reverse map{s@.*@($b=$&)=~y:/\\:\\/:,$&.reverse$b@e;print;y@/\\@\\/@;$_}<>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shell Scripting!!

```
#!/bin/sh

rm temp
touch temp
file=$1
for STRING in `cat $1`
do
   printf $STRING >> temp
   for ((COUNT=0; COUNT<${#STRING}; COUNT++))
   do
      RECORD[$COUNT]=${STRING:$COUNT:1}
   done
   for ((REV_COUNT=${#STRING}; REV_COUNT>=0; REV_COUNT--))
      do
        if [ "${RECORD[$REV_COUNT]}" = "\\" ]; then
            printf "/" >> temp
        elif [ "${RECORD[$REV_COUNT]}" = "/" ]; then
            printf "\\" >> temp
        else
           printf "${RECORD[$REV_COUNT]}" >> temp
        fi
      done
   echo >> temp
done
cat temp
tac temp > temp2
for STRING in `cat temp2`
do
   for ((COUNT=0; COUNT<${#STRING}; COUNT++))
   do
      RECORD[$COUNT]=${STRING:$COUNT:1}
   if [ "${RECORD[$COUNT]}" = "\\" ]; then
            printf "/"
   elif [ "${RECORD[$COUNT]}" = "/" ]; then
            printf "\\"
   else
           printf "${RECORD[$COUNT]}"
   fi
   done
echo
done
```

I/O

```
./solution in

+------+
|./..\.|
|/....\|
|\..../|
|.\../.|
+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 26 bytes

CJam is newer than this challenge, so this answer is not eligible for the green checkmark, but it was a fun exercise anyway

```
qN/{{_W%"\/"_W%er+}%z}2*N*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

### Explanation

```
qN/{{_W%"\/"_W%er+}%z}2*N*
qN/                        "Read STDIN and split on newlines.";
   {                 }2*   "Execute this block twice.";
    {             }%       "Map this block onto each line.";
     _W%                   "Duplicate and reverse.";
        "\/"               "Push the string '\/'.";
            _W%            "Duplicate and reverse.";
               er          "Character transliteration, swaps slashes and backslashes.";
                 +         "Append to first half of the line.";
                    z      "Zip, i.e. transpose the map.";
                        N* "Join with newlines.";
```

The transposing at the end leads the the second flipping to be performed along the columns. At the end we transpose the map again, so we end up with the original orientation.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 95 bytes

*Inspired by Joey's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/763/80745).*

```powershell
filter x{$_;$_[40..0]|%{$_-split'/'-replace'\\','/'-join'\'}},($args|%{-join(,($_|% t*y)|x)})|x
```

Note: `40` because the author posts the comment `Let's say the input is at most 16 rows and 40 characters`.

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

filter x{$_;$_[40..0]|%{$_-split'/'-replace'\\','/'-join'\'}}
,($args|%{-join(,($_|% t*y)|x)})|x

}

@(
    ,( ("+---",
        "|./.",
        "|/.."),
        "+------+",
        "|./..\.|",
        "|/....\|",
        "|\..../|",
        "|.\../.|",
        "+------+")
    ,( ("+\/",
        "/\/"),
        "+\/\/+",
        "/\/\/\",
        "\/\/\/",
        "+/\/\+")
    ,( ("+---",
        "|...",
        "|..\"),
        "+------+",
        "|......|",
        "|..\/..|",
        "|../\..|",
        "|......|",
        "+------+")
) | % {
    $m,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f @m
    "$result"-eq"$expected"
    $result
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True
+------+
|./..\.|
|/....\|
|\..../|
|.\../.|
+------+
True
+\/\/+
/\/\/\
\/\/\/
+/\/\+
True
+------+
|......|
|..\/..|
|../\..|
|......|
+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
øṀ¶+∞
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDuOG5gMK2K+KIniIsIiIsIlwiKy0tLVxcbnwuLy5cXG58Ly4uXCIiXQ==)

```
øṀ    # Vertically mirror, flipping /\
  ¶+  # Append a newline
    ∞ # Palindromise
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby - 105

```
t=->s{s.tr '/\\\\','\\\\/'}
$<.read.split.map{|l|print l+=t[l.reverse]+"
"
l}.reverse.map{|l|print t[l]}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Golfscript - 44 chars

```
n%{.-1%'/'/{'\\'/'/'*}%'\\'*+}%.-1%{-1%}%+n*
```

result

```
$ cat in2
+-/|/\
/\|//-
$ cat in2 | golfscript codegolf-761.gs 
+-/|/\/\|\-+
/\|//--\\|/\
\/|\\--//|\/
+-\|\/\/|/-+
```

#### Another script that only work for example and does not flip for '\' - 32 chars

```
n%{.-1%'/'/'\\'*+}%.-1%{-1%}%+n*
```

result

```
$ cat in
+---
|./.
|/..
$ cat in | golfscript codegolf-761.gs 
+------+
|./..\.|
|/....\|
|\..../|
|.\../.|
+------+
$
```

Comment: `\\` needs to be flipped as well.

Comment: @Nabb, thanks, that made my code huge :P

Comment: Mark: Use variables for repeated strings if it makes it shorter. Although there are a few other tricks that you can try to figure out before I post my answer later.

Comment: @Nabb, Thanks, I will try to figure out and let me have 30 minutes :D

Comment: @Nabb, I still couldn't figure out, you may post yours.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 76 bytes

```hs
c '/'='\\';c '\\'='/';c x=x;i=(c<$>)
q#x=x++q(reverse x)
f=((i<$>)#).map(i#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYo7DsMgEER7TrGSLQGygAPYpHGbVGndIGedoNj4A4kofHeyKUbznmZeLr5xnksZgRtu@TDwlpDKkhNmm1tvxdjVF8n2irRpdnHgF4@IkCWbrBD@v1ZSL24TvpJlcT6AhccKGToFT0z9GhKGFKEFOt1g@6R7Oq4Bapgosw8YIZdGKcVObTQ7jdY/)

```hs
-- Only / and \ get converted, all other chars are passed as is
c '/'='\\';c '\\'='/';c x=x

-- "Invert" the string (that is switch all / and \ in it)
-- Just map our conversion function over the string
i = (c<$>)

-- Helper: Concatenate a list with its reversed copy (with the given function applied to the copy)
q # x = x ++ q (reverse x)

-- the resulting function:
f = ((i<$>)#) . -- produce the lower half of the image by reversing the upper half and inverting slashes in each line
    map (i#) -- produce the upper half or the image (by concating each input line with its reversed, inverted version)
```

Answer (score 0):

## MS-SQL 2017, 243 bytes

**input**:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100) ='+---'+CHAR(10)+'|...'+CHAR(10)+'|..\';
```

*compressed*:

```
declare @t TABLE(l INT IDENTITY(1,1),s CHAR(40));INSERT INTO @t(s)SELECT value+TRANSLATE(REVERSE(value),'\/','/\')FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s,char(10));SELECT s FROM(SELECT l,s FROM @t UNION ALL SELECT 1e3-l,TRANSLATE(s,'\/','/\')FROM @t)b ORDER BY l
```

*human readable*:

```
declare @t TABLE(l INT IDENTITY(1,1),s CHAR(40));
INSERT INTO @t(s)
  SELECT value+TRANSLATE(REVERSE(value), '\/', '/\')
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s,char(10));

SELECT s 
FROM(
   SELECT l, s FROM @t 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 1e3-l, TRANSLATE(s, '\/', '/\') FROM @t
  )b 
ORDER BY l
```

**output** (as text in ex.management studio):

```
+------+                                
|......|                                
|..\/..|                                
|../\..|                                
|......|                                
+------+                                

(6 rows affected)
```